# Using drools globals in the KIE Execution Server to interact with external services

Tags: java, drools, kie

It is clear, that in order to interact with the external world I could use globals (in this case for calling external services) or channels (eg. for getting results of the ruleset execution) from a `drl` file.

But what happens if I am about to execute my rules within the `KIE` execution server?
 How do I accomplish passing service references as globals using the `REST API` (and its corresponding java client API)?